# Как эксель преобразует число во временной формат?

Tags: java, excel

Нужно написать метод на java для преобразования числа в формат времени.
Есть два столбца в экселе, в одном записан коэффициент, допустим 4.24 а в другом столбце получается время 5:47:36.
Я делаю автоматизацию отчета и нужно чтобы 5:47:36
получалось сразу вместо 4.24.
я не могу понять, как эксель преобразует число во временной формат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алгоритм довольно простой: число `4.24` умножается на количество миллисекунд в сутках:
`86 400 000` - получается результат в миллисекундах, который уже можно перевести в дату. Получается, что цифры целой части (`4`) означают число полных дней и при переводе просто во время (в пределах суток) эту цифру можно не учитывать, оставляя только знаки после запятой: перевод `4.24` и `0.24` вернёт один и тот же результат.

На Java можно написать следующим образом:

```java
Date date = new Date((long) (4.24 * 86400000L));
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: Дополню: в Excel 1 час=1/24, 1 минута = 1/1440 (24*60), 1 секунда - 1/86400  (24*60*60)